# Transferring elements from one array to another array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create an array of values that are greater than a certain threshold entered by the user, so I'm transferring one array of total seconds and keeping the values that are greater than the threshold. I can transfer the values I need appropriately, but I can't seem to print the results without it also printing the ending elements that contain no values.

Below is the code I've written:

```
public static int[] overGivenMinutes(int minThres, int arrayValues[]) {
    int[] greaterThanThres = new int[arrayValues.length];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayValues.length; i++) {
        int minutes = arrayValues[i] / 60;
        if (minutes > minThres) {
            greaterThanThres[j++] = arrayValues[i];
        }
    }
    return greaterThanThres;
}
```

When the user enters the 30 min mark, it prints:

```
Time[00] = 56:38
Time[01] = 34:27
Time[02] = 51:04
Time[03] = 40:07
Time[04] = 43:34
Time[05] = 00:00
Time[06] = 00:00
Time[07] = 00:00
Time[08] = 00:00
Time[09] = 00:00
```

I'm trying to figure out what I need to do to remove the elements 5-9 since they are empty, and I cannot figure out how to. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Does the return have to be an array? or is a list acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int[] overGivenMinutes(int minThres, int arrayValues[]){
    int tmp[] = new int[arrayValues.length];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayValues.length; i++){
        int minutes = arrayValues[i] / 60;
        if (minutes > minThres){
            tmp[j++] = arrayValues[i];
        }
    }
    int greaterThanThres[] = new int[j];
    System.arrayCopy(tmp,0,greaterThanThres,0,j);
    return greaterThanThres;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Bill Mair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75836238/2422776) has the right idea - you need to return a smaller array without "dangling" elements. However, it may be easier to achieve this by streaming and filtering the array and then collecting it to an array than by creating a new array and then returning a partial copy of it:

```
public static int[] overGivenMinutes(int minThres, int[] arrayValues){
    return Arrays.stream(arrayValues).filter(i -> i / 60 > minThres).toArray();
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to go into the collections streaming API as it appears that the OP is still learning the ropes. I could also have "reused" the input array but that would have been destructive to the input data.

Comment: Yes I totally am just getting the ropes. I appreciate both of y'all and your inputs because both were very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the array length at the start. So you are left with empty values. What you can do is use an implementation of `java.util.List` such as `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> greaterThanThres = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

When you want to add an element, just push it to the list.

```
greaterThanThres.add(arrayValues[i]);
```

This is one alternative. Or you can simply loop through your array again in the end and clean it up according to your condition.